# Change div position if partially hidden

Tags: jquery

Please how to dynamically change position of div if it is partially hidden.
I have a main wrapper `div` which has `overflow:hidden`. I cant change this, cause I am using an animation.

How do I dynamically detect if div is partially/fully hidden when button clicked and then change its position.

[image]

Comment: Can you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?! However, if I understand your question and to give a short answer, basically you've test for the scrollposition and compare this with your div-offset.

Comment: OK I am making a fiddle.

Comment: What have you tried? This information is important. If you haven't tried anything, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) to find the y-coordinate of the bottom of the div, and see if that is greater than the height of the window. If so, move it above.

This works for a non-scrolling page. If your page scrolls, it will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: I hope you mean `jQuery.fn.offset` instead of `jQuery.fn.position` ;)

Comment: ...and `jQuery.fn.outerHeight` is here the better choice, so I think :P

Comment: @yckart: I would agree again. For the offset vs. position part, it's likely that `position` would have worked fine, as long as he wasn't checking the position of an element within an offset container. But still, there's a chance of failure there, and `offset` should always return the expected value, so I agree that offset is better.